# How to change the lazy loading property from woocommerce?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, woocommerce, lazy-loading

My website is too long to charge, and apparently, it's caused by image lazy-loading. When I inspect the element (the image on the front page), I get :

```html
<img width="300" height="300" src="https://miro-labo.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Capture-decran-2022-08-19-131727-300x300.png" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt="" loading="lazy" srcset="https://miro-labo.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Capture-decran-2022-08-19-131727-300x300.png 300w, https://miro-labo.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Capture-decran-2022-08-19-131727-150x150.png 150w, https://miro-labo.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Capture-decran-2022-08-19-131727-100x100.png 100w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px">
```

What file (PHP or js?) do I need to edit to remove the loading="lazy"?
I am a little new to coding so please forgive my lack of knowledge ;)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can put `add_filter( 'wp_lazy_loading_enabled', '__return_false' );` in your theme's `functions.php` file Or can use any available plugin for **Disable Lazy Loading** and if you're using Jetpack or any other optimization or Cache plugin that enable lazy loading then you can turn off lazy load settings on those plugin options.